# Using C++ method in c#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm writing a c# console application that uses a C++ class library. In C++ language class library I have a method:

```
public:bool GetMDC(char fileName[], char mdcStrOut[]){
    // My Code goes Here
}
```

This method gets a file path in `fileName` parameter and puts a value in `mdcStrOut`.

I add this class library as reference to my C# console application. when I want to call GetMDC method the method needs two `sbyte` parameters. So it's signature in c# is `GetMDC(sbyte* fileName, sbyte* mdcStrOut)`.

My code looks like this:

```
unsafe{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
    var _mdc = new TelsaMDC.TelsaMDCDetection();
    var outPut = new sbyte();
    fixed (byte* p = bytes)
    {
        var sp = (sbyte*)p;
        //SP is now what you want
        _mdc.GetMDC(sp, &outPut);
    }
}
```

It works without error. But the problem is that `outPut` variable only contains the first character of `mdcStrOut`. I'm unfamiliar with C++. I know that I'm passing the memory address of `output` to the GetMDC. So how can I get the value of it in my console application?

**EDIT**

when I declare `output` variable like this `var outPut = new sbyte[MaxLength]` I get an error on `_mdc.GetMDC(sp, &outPut);` line on the `&` sign. It says: `Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('sbyte[]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `outPut` is a single byte.
You need to create a receive buffer, for example, `var outPut = new sbyte[MaxLength]`.

```
unsafe{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
    var _mdc = new TelsaMDC.TelsaMDCDetection();
    var outPut = new sbyte[256];  // Bad practice. Avoid using this!
    fixed (byte* p = bytes, p2 = outPut)
    {
        var sp = (sbyte*)p;
        var sp2 = (sbyte*)p2;
        //SP is now what you want
        _mdc.GetMDC(sp, sp2);
    }
}
```

Also, I recommend to rewrite the code to avoid possible buffer overflow because the function GetMDC does not know the size of the buffer.

Comment: Just do it the same way as the first parameter `bytes`